# Mongo dropAllUsersFromDatabase command not work by using MongoClient

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I am new to MongoDB and have below code for dropping database. Before dropping the database, I have run a command [dropAllUsersFromDatabase](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dropAllUsersFromDatabase/) for removing all users from this database. However, this command didn't remove those users.

```
private final MongoClient mongo;

public void drop(final String databaseName) {

    final MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase(databaseName);

    final BasicDBObject commandArguments = new BasicDBObject();

    commandArguments.put("dropAllUsersFromDatabase", 1);

    final BasicDBObject command = new BasicDBObject(commandArguments);

    database.runCommand(command);

    database.drop();
}
```

Those users still remaining in [system.users collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/system-users-collection/) in the *admin* database, which mongo stores user authentication and authorization information. For example:

```
{
"_id" : "57b3cc41851cb3aab00a3c84.57b3cc41851cb3aab00a3c84",
"user" : "57b3cc41851cb3aab00a3c84",
"db" : "57b3cc41851cb3aab00a3c84",
"credentials" : {
    "SCRAM-SHA-1" : {
        "iterationCount" : 10000,
        "salt" : "8LjAxK/7z9yJLBfAchkLGg==",
        "storedKey" : "HmktZ1GF+uQ8MJqIzY3/lU7VJEg=",
        "serverKey" : "9CyQxvtK9BWT80la8p4o+kHyNwc="
    }
},
"roles" : [ 
    {
        "role" : "dbOwner",
        "db" : "57b3cc41851cb3aab00a3c84"
    }
]
}
```

But, if I execute the command by mongo as below, it will delete those users correctly.

```
db.runCommand({ dropAllUsersFromDatabase: 1});
```

The login authoriztion are same and there has no exception when running **`database.runCommand(command);`**

Comment: Have you double-checked that it was the *admin* database you were trying to delete users from?

Comment: Hi Bowden, thanks for the reply. The database of `final MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase(databaseName);` is not _admin_, it is the database which I want to drop all users of it.

Comment: And also I have execute  `db.runCommand({ dropAllUsersFromDatabase: 1});` on the database which I want to drop all users of it, not the _admin_ one, by execute `use some_database` before the command above.

Comment: Can you clarify in which database you're finding those users still remaining, after you've run the command? In your question you say they are "*in admin.system.users db*", which I interpreted as being in the *admin* database.

Comment: I am finding those users still remaining in [system.users collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/system-users-collection/) in the _admin_ database, which mongo stores user authentication and authorization information.

Comment: But the dropAllUsersFromDatabase command shall be run on the database you want to drop all users.

Comment: It looks like your users are in the admin database. I think you need to read up on [users in mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/), particularly the part about the authentication database.

Comment: Yes, I see. Those users will be created in the admin database which is authentication database. But, the `dropAllUsersFromDatabase` command will remove all users from the database on which you run the command. If I run on _some_database_, it shall delete all users of _some_database_ in the **system.users collection** in _admin_ database. At least, it works when I use mongo shell, but not java mongo client(com.mongodb.MongoClient)

Comment: you'd best clarify that in your question.